# What is the meaning of thread count in process (wmic)

Tags: windows, process, wmic

When I'm running `wmic` query via command line, I'm detected a line with ThreadCount value.

I don't know about the meaning of `ThreadCount`.

**I'm running this wmic query:**

```
wmic process where (Caption like '%explorer%') get * /format:list
```

**Output of above query:**

```
Caption=explorer.exe
CommandLine=C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
CreationClassName=Win32_Process
CreationDate=20140725092933.908032+330
CSCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem
CSName=DIGITALFOX
Description=explorer.exe
ExecutablePath=C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
ExecutionState=
Handle=1820
HandleCount=856
InstallDate=
KernelModeTime=50388323
MaximumWorkingSetSize=1380
MinimumWorkingSetSize=200
Name=explorer.exe
OSCreationClassName=Win32_OperatingSystem
OSName=Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2
OtherOperationCount=90378
OtherTransferCount=2089300
PageFaults=63847
PageFileUsage=32724
ParentProcessId=1776
PeakPageFileUsage=70672
PeakVirtualSize=284794880
PeakWorkingSetSize=42564
Priority=8
PrivatePageCount=33509376
ProcessId=1820
QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage=48
QuotaPagedPoolUsage=388
QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage=53
QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage=490
ReadOperationCount=1543
ReadTransferCount=4529679
SessionId=1
Status=
TerminationDate=
ThreadCount=30
UserModeTime=34008218
VirtualSize=235257856
WindowsVersion=6.1.7600
WorkingSetSize=33030144
WriteOperationCount=6
WriteTransferCount=696
```

*What is the meaning of ThreadCount in above data?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About Processes and Threads
Each process provides the resources needed to execute a program. A process has a virtual address space, executable code, open handles to system objects, a security context, a unique process identifier, environment variables, a priority class, minimum and maximum working set sizes, and at least one thread of execution. Each process is started with a single thread, often called the primary thread, but can create additional threads from any of its threads.

A thread is the entity within a process that can be scheduled for execution. All threads of a process share its virtual address space and system resources. In addition, each thread maintains exception handlers, a scheduling priority, thread local storage, a unique thread identifier, and a set of structures the system will use to save the thread context until it is scheduled. The thread context includes the thread's set of machine registers, the kernel stack, a thread environment block, and a user stack in the address space of the thread's process. Threads can also have their own security context, which can be used for impersonating clients.

ms-help://MS.MSSDK.1033/MS.WinSDK.1033/dllproc/base/about_processes_and_threads.htm

Answer (score 2):

In this the Threadcount is the No of threads that process is currently using.

In your situation the process explorer is using 30 threads.

Thread count is used for avoiding orphan threads so before closing the process thread count should be zero.